# Boolean Modifier acts like the object has no volume

Tags: modifiers

I added a cube and a cylinder.
When i now substract the cube from the cylinder using a Boolean Modifier it looks like this:

[image]

Like the cylinder has just a shell and no volume.

I checked the normals
i checked if there are any missing faces (what shouldnt be possible cause i just added the cube...but in case)
There are no other modifiers on them.
I added another cube in the exact same location and subtracted it with the same boolean...and this one works.
i just wann know...

please halp

Comment: Please attach your .blend using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: .....i should have thought of that.... now i deleted the non working cube

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the scale of the two objects are different so I'm assuming you scaled one of them.

If you resized the cube or cylinder try using 'apply object transform' and mark the scale and rotation. Probably even if you see the object as smaller or bigger, Blender doesn't take into account that the object has a new volume.

Most of the times it will fix things so that afterwards you can successfully apply the Boolean modifier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is duplicated vertex, removing them will probably fix this issue.

If you are a beginner, in Blender  2.8+ to remove doubles right click in the viewport while in *Edit Mode*, with all of your vertex selected.

Hover on *Merge* and select *Merge by Distance*.

In older versions do the same thing but don't right click. Instead press <kbd>W</kbd>  to open the specials menu, then select *Remove Doubles*.